# What is Neon with respect to Android?

Tags: android, neon

I'm a beginner in Android. My friend heard "Neon". So I did Google and found [this](http://www.arm.com/products/processors/technologies/neon.php)

Referring it, Neon is related to multimedia for Android OS or all mobile OS, is it?  Please share me more.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Neon is an ARM co-processor, meant for vector processing. Neon is used for multimedia data processing. It is an optional co-processor, the Android Linux kernel may or may not have support for this. (Eclair days)

However if Google provides any Android Application APIs to access Neon, then you can safely use it in your application.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a co-processor.  It's more of an instruction set extension.

Answer (score 16):

NEON is extremely powerful and easy to program. It doesn't solve performance issues, but simply eliminates them in most cases.

NEON intrinsics suck performance-wise, I suggest writing native codes for NEON.

- Java : pistol
- C/C++ : assault rifle
- Assembly : machine gun
- NEON : vulcan cannon, or A-10 tank killer

Honestly, I'm not exaggerating in any way. NEON is THAT powerful.

Comment: Anybody else think Star Trek only to find out a vulcan cannon is a machine gun?

Comment: just love your comparison! :D

Answer (score 0):

There is an official usage example in the NDK source reproduced at: https://github.com/android/platform_development/tree/android-6.0.1_r16/ndk/samples/hello-neon

It is used from NDK, so the interesting files are the `.c` files under `jni/`.

You can build and install it with:

```
ndk-build
android update project -p . -t android-22
ant clean
ant debug
ant installd
```